# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import certifi
import csv
import os


#to iterate through the .txt files
for filename in os.listdir('ecom-companies/'):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        f = open('ecom-companies/'+ filename, 'r')
        contents = f.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(contents,'html.parser')
        for i in soup.find('div',{'class':'spotlight-product-info half-margin-bottom','data-product-type':'B'}):
            companyName = i.find('h1').text.strip()
            ovrRating = i.find('span',{'itemprop':'ratingValue'}).text.strip()
            reviewsCount = i.find('span',{'itemprop':'reviewCount'}).text.strip()
            with open('ecom_main.csv','a') as outputfile:
                outputfile.write(companyName+','+ovrRating+','+reviewsCount)
```

I want to crawl a website, scrap data and store it in a csv file. I have saved the parsed html response of all the pages I want to crawl in a directory 'ecom-companies' as .txt files. I ran the code above and got the error 'AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'text'. I am guessing it is because there are file names that contain integers(for eg: 1AutomationWiz.txt, 3Dsellers.txt etc). But I am not sure, nor do I know how to rectify it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error stack trace

Comment: The method `find()` in a string returns the index of where the searched part was found.  
So `companyName = i.find('h1').text.strip()` is where your error occurs

Comment: Also you used method `find` in for loop. You probably wanted to find all the matching objects. So use `soup.find_all` there.